# DirectWrite: How to get rendered bitmap data

Tags: direct2d, directwrite

Is there a way to get rendered bitmap image using DirectWrite and Direct2D ?

Like FreeType2's FT_GlyphSlot->bitmap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a ID2D1Bitmap first, then use ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromRenderTarget to copy the data from render target.

Comment: Thank you. Is this a most simple way? Isn't DirectWrite provide bitmap utility api ? (I couldn't found it)

Comment: Do you mean convert font to a bitmap?

Comment: Yes. I checked out and found that ID2D1Factory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget() is needed and some more procedure to get actual bitmap data. I feel too complex to do such a simple task...

Comment: not sure if this can help you, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376597/Outline-Text-With-DirectWrite

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and you don't need to use Direct2D for that. Use `CreateGlyphRunAnalysis` and then call `GetAlphaTextureBounds` to get resulting bitmap bounds, then allocated buffer and call `CreateAlphaTexture`. This fills your buffer with opacity mask for a glyph run you want to render.